# setting a complex type as nullable c#

Tags: c#, nullable, complextype

I have the following class

```
public class Excercise
{
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public bool? Present { get; set; }
    public Physical Physical { get; set; }
}
```

Physical is a complex type:

```
public class Physical
{
    public string Reference1 { get; set; }
    public bool Valid{ get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to make Physical property on the exercise class, a nullable field.
To me, ordinarily this just means adding a ? to the attribute.

However, when I do this on the complex type I get the error: 
CS0453 C# The type must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable'

Is this error simply telling me I don't need to set this as nullable if I want to ignore it when comes to populating the attributes of this class?

Is it possible that I can just set null values, or leave them empty?

Comment: You do not need to make `Physical` explicitly nullable. It is a class, classes are reference types and are nullable by default. Had `Physical` been a struct you would have needed to make it nullable.

Comment: yes.... you dont need to set it as `?` because class property is reference type and if you are not passing anything to it then it would be null.

Comment: If you have a situation where you want to have two possible states, has value or has no value, then `Physical Physical { get; set; }` is sufficient as you can have `Physical == null`, but if you need to model three states then you need something like the `Maybe<>` type so that you'd have `Maybe<Physical> PhysicalMaybe { get; set; }`. `Maybe<>` lets you model the situations like a record in a database - it may have a value, it may be `null`, or it may be missing. If you have the latter situation I can post the code that I use if you like.

Comment: @Enigmativity thanks. it's enough to not have to populate this part of the class, but thanks for your time